# Javascript cannot read property 'x' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game, and I get this error when I assign my collision function to a variable. I want to call my function inside another function, but I get this error. How do I get rid of it? The error is the 'x' in the 'let collision' function below:

```
var playerScore = 0;
let addScore = () => {
playerScore += 10;
document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = playerScore;
};
let collision = (player, faller) => {
return player.x < faller.x + faller.width && player.x + player.width > faller.x &&
  player.y < faller.y + faller.height && player.y + player.height > faller.y
};

let draw = (millisecondsElapsed) => {
    game.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    fallers.forEach((faller) => {
        faller.draw();
        collision();
        //COLLISION FUNCTION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          if (collision === true) {
              game.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              addScore();
            };
        console.log(collision);
        faller.move(millisecondsElapsed);
    });

    player.draw();

    // Remove fallers that have hit the ground. You might have other reasons to remove fallers.
    fallers = fallers.filter((faller) => {
        return faller.y < canvas.height;
    });
};
```

Comment: What is not clear about the error? *"How do I get rid of it?"* Make sure to not pass `undefined` to the function. You are calling `collision` without passing any arguments to it: `collision();`. Which behavior did you expect exactly? I think you might want to read a tutorial about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Comment: `if (collision === true)` is wrong. `collision` is the name of the function, not the value it returned. It should be `if (collision(player, faller))`. But where have you set `player`?

Comment: I expected the falling blocks in my full code to disappear when the player catches them.

Comment: I meant, how did you expect `collision()` to work if you don't pass any arguments to it? You defined the function to expect two arguments and you are calling the function with no arguments.

Comment: @FelixKling I would encourage you to remember that many on Stack Overflow are still learning their craft, and there's no need to be so hostile ("Why would you do that") to someone trying to learn.

Comment: @machineghost: You are right, edited my comment. However, there are better places to *learn* the basics of a programming language than Stack Overflow (http://eloquentjavascript.net/ for example).

Comment: @FelixKling Fair enough (and thanks for the edit!).  I think part of the problem is that when you are new to something, even if you would be better served by "RTFM-ing", if you don't even know what's in "TFM" you might instead go to a sub-optimal place (Stack Overflow).  Perhaps the best solution for a situation like this would be to post an answer with a link to (for instance) an eloquentjavascript.net explanation of how arguments work.  That way OP gets both an answer and a pointer to where they can "help themselves", and others coming after them can similarly benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collision(player, faller)` is a function defined to accept two arguments. You pass it none in your `draw` function when you write:

```
collision();
```

The default value for arguments that are not passed to a function is `undefined`. Thus, when you try to access `x` or `y` on either `player` or `faller`, an error is thrown: there is no logical value to return from a property access on "absent" values like `null` or `undefined`.

```
(null).x //=> throws Error
(undefined).x //=> throws Error
```

You were probably intending to pass your `player` and `faller` variables defined earlier, and cache the result to determine whether or not the two collided:

```
let collided = collision(player, faller);
if (collided) {
    game.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    addScore();
}
console.log(collided);
```

**Full Revised Code:**

```js
var playerScore = 0;
let addScore = () => {
playerScore += 10;
document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = playerScore;
};
let collision = (player, faller) => {
return player.x < faller.x + faller.width && player.x + player.width > faller.x &&
  player.y < faller.y + faller.height && player.y + player.height > faller.y
};

let draw = (millisecondsElapsed) => {
    game.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    fallers.forEach((faller) => {
        faller.draw();
        //COLLISION FUNCTION!!!!!!!
        let collided = collision(player, faller);
        if (collided) {
            game.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            addScore();
        }
        console.log(collided);
        faller.move(millisecondsElapsed);
    });

    player.draw();

    // Remove fallers that have hit the ground. You might have other reasons to remove fallers.
    fallers = fallers.filter((faller) => {
        return faller.y < canvas.height;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a `collision` function that expects certain arguments:

```
let collision = (player, faller) => {
```

but you aren't passing it any arguments (most importantly, you aren't passing it a `player` argument):

```
collision();
```

As a result, `player` is undefined and you get your error when you try to do:

```
player.x
```

because there is no `undefined.x`.

**EDIT**

As zfrisch suggested in the comments, one way you could fix this would be to define a default value for the `player` argument.  If you do this then even when you call `collision` without arguments the browser would still have a value to use for `player`.

You can specify a default value by adding an `=` and the default value.  For instance, if you did the following:

```
let collision = (player={x: 1}, faller) => {
    // ...
};
collision();
```

It will be exactly the same as if you had done:

```
collision({x: 1});
```